# Exiftool - changing PENTAX related EXIF tags to Pentax

Tags: cmd, jpeg, batch-processing, exiftool

I just discovered that GIMP 2.10 removes JPG EXIF data because of the "PENTAX" in uppercase present in the EXIF data (the bug is described [here](https://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/20941-pentax-exif-data-stripped) and [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/2253)).

Tried Exif Pilot freeware and found out the EXIF fields:

Make=PENTAX

Model=PENTAX K-x

Fixing them to "Pentax K-x" and "Pentax" solves the problem but requires me to do it manually one by one in Exif Pilot GUI.

Is there any way to do this as batch for a whole folder with JPG files? I tried to find some Exiftool parameters to replace "PENTAX" with "Pentax" but to keep the model information correctly but no success so I would appreciate help.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, Juhele. You have a few points, so you should be familiar with how to use SO from http://stackoverflow.com/help. Please copy and paste the code, as text, that you are trying to make work into the question. Until then, it is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using exiftool, you could use this command
`exiftool -api "filter=s/PENTAX/Pentax/" -TagsFromFile @ -Model -Make /path/to/files/`

The [`-api Filter` option](https://exiftool.org/ExifTool.html#Filter) will do a regex substitution changing `PENTAX` into `Pentax`.  The [`-TagsFromFile` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#tagsFromFile-SRCFILE-or-FMT) will copy the modified `Model` and `Make` tags back into the file.  It will not affect any file that doesn't contain `PENTAX` in those two tags.

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you so much StarGeek - this solved my problem. Also thanks much for the additional information regarding the Exiftool parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is lacking in having the generic command grep for this common task on many other systems. The jpeg files are binary but like a PDF the Meta data itself is held as plain text. Do check your text string is similar to below otherwise you will/may need to parse both PENTAX entries separately as single words.

[image]

So in this fixed case it it should be easy to use any binary file reader / writer and "Find aNd Replace" the text string. Just ensure it is byte for byte the same length.

```
Find    =PENTAXPENTAX K-x
Replace =PentaxPentax K-x
```

DO NOT use Notepad and sadly the native cmd tool `Debug.exe` was removed long ago. However you might use inbuilt PowerShell of which lit is an advocate. :-)

You could use the well known exiftool but that is yet another exe to add to your dedicated file utilities collection.

Otherwise consider downloading a more universal small CMD batch file like dbenhams [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) which can be used for hundreds of other file type tasks.

`jrepl PENTAXPENTAX PentaxPentax /M /f user-default-avatar.jpg /o -`

[image]

So the code you need to consider is how you write a loop **for do**ing all your files and thus I will suggest you use `For /?` and look at the options to add a folder of files something like `For %F in (*.jpg) do jrepl ...` However, as there are no error checks or backup, I suggest it be something like this

```
@echo off & Title Replacing PENTAX
set "Find=PENTAX"
set "Replace=Pentax"

for %%F in (*.jpg) do @(
echo replacing %find% in %%F
if not exist %%~nF.bak copy %%F /B %%~nF.bak /B >nul
@jrepl "%Find%" "%Replace%" /M /F %%F /o -
)
```